# repair chip in edge of glass cooktop

Tags: repair, glass, cooktops

Our induction cooktop has a chip in the edge of the glass.  It is about 1/2 inch long and 1/4 inch deep in the beveled edge.  Any suggestions how to repair it?
[image]

Comment: Good thing you told us what we're looking at, because that could have been a shot of deep space from the Hubble Telescope from _before_ the mirrors got adjusted. Not all cell phone cameras are the best, but I'm sure yours could get _something_ more focused than that...

Comment: I have replaced the photo

Answer (score 1):

Those cannot be repaired. The cooktop should be replaced. There may be a suggestion of a type of "Band-Aid" repair. However this happened to my son's cooktop recently and he was told it must be replaced because of the greater risk of cracks radiating from that area.

Comment: The other way to prevent cracking would be to polish the damaged area so it's smooth -- glass  cracks start where stress is concentrated and a smooth curve distributes stress better. Not knowing what kind of glass they used I won't hazard a guess on what kind of polishing would work; a professional glass shop might know (or might not, but at least would have the business insurance to cover it if they make a mistake). Of course depending on where the chip is this might also affect how well the range is sealed against spills, so replacement might be the better answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a start of a crack there. This will keep propogating, faster because of thermal cycling as the top heats up and cools down.

**I would advise replacement.** However, if you are going to try repairing it, then I  would suggest a strap or a bridge, across the chip, to hold the crack closed.

Comment: Since you're suggesting that it _could_ be repaired, it would be very useful if you could offer suggestions as to _how_ to go about repairing this, and what a "strap or a bridge" might look like, how it would be installed, what it would be made of, etc.